# Suitelet cannot be accessed by multiple Users , only owner of script can access it

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I created a Suitelet script and say owner is "A" for that. Now when other user say "B"(Administrator access) is trying to access this suitelet , its throwing below error

"An unexpected error has occured.Please click here to notify support and provide your contact information".

I found a workaround for this , if we change the owner of the suitelet script to "B" , then "B" is able to access the suitelet but "A" cannot. This means at a time only one user(owner) can access the Suitelet.

Is there any fix for this so that all users can access suitelet . Please advice .

Answer (score 3):

In script deployment the STATUS=Testing , thats the reason its throwing the error. I modified it to Released. It fixed the issue .

Comment: That, and make sure that anyone who should have access is in listed in the permissions.